# How to limit network-manager to a single interface?

Tags: network-manager, configuration

Is it possible to give network-manager control over single interface only? Such that further added devices are not controlled by nm by default.

I would like to assign it to a specific wireless adapter, but need to control other devices manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default (*i.e.*, unless you have `managed=true` in `NetworkManager.conf`), NetworkManager ignores any interface which has an entry in `/etc/network/interfaces`. If you don't want to specify any settings there, just add a `manual` entry:

```
iface ethX inet manual
```

Comment: Thank you, I might use this as a partial solution. However, is there a way to prevent network-manager from controlling devices introduced in the future, without having to specify each explicitly?

Comment: @alm Looking at `man NetworkManager.conf`, this does not seem to be possible.